# Experience with database repair tools for mdf files?

Tags: sql-server, data-recovery

I've got a HDD which is encrypted with petya-green. I used "Disk Internals NTFS Recovery" for recovering the databasefiles which are needed.

Than I tried to simpl attach the databasefiles to a new Microsoft SQL Server 2012 installation. But the mdf files seems to be corrupted and need a repair.

Now installed several repair tools for evaluation. "Stellar Phoenix SQL Database Repair" seems to me like making a good result. But also "Kernel for SQL Database" seems to be produce a good repair. Now I need to make a decision which tool I have to buy.

Does anyone have experience with this 2 tools (or other tools)? Or other tools and give me a tip which one I should buy?

It can be run on Windows or Linux.
If it is free it is good, if I have to pay for is also fine (if the databse repair succesfull ;-) )

Thanks in advanced :-)

Comment: Have you seen this?   http://www.computerworld.com/article/3054518/cybercrime-hacking/petya-ransomware-cracked-get-password-to-decrypt-hard-drive-for-free.html

Comment: Yes, but this HDD is infected by the green version of petya. But we already brute forced the decryption key. But unfortunately  the decryption is not working correctly.... So I still thinking about to repair the databasefile.